# How to calculate Maximum absolute error

Tags: equation-solving

If `fapp[x_]= 2x+432x^(2)/2+908*x^(3)+3x^(5)` and `fexact[x_]:= Sin[x]/x`
also if `x` belongs to [0,2], then how we can calculate maximum absolute error.

---

Comment: `Maximize[{(fapp[x] - fexact[x])^2, 0 <= x <= 2}, x]`

Comment: First of all thank you so much Mr. Henrik Schumacher. But I could not understand why you taking whole square of exact solution?

Comment: In constrast to the absolute value function, squaring is a differentiable operation. Since it is also monotone on $[0,\infty[$, finding the maximum of `Abs[fapp[x] - fexact[x]]` is equivalent to finding the maximum of `(fapp[x] - fexact[x])^2`. The advantage of the latter is that `Maximize` may use elementary calculus to determine extrema (since `(fapp[x] - fexact[x])^2` is differentiable in `x`).

Comment: By the way, `fapp` is a _really bad_ approximation of  `fexact`. `1 - x^2/6 + x^4/120` should provide a much better fifth-order approximation (this is the fifth-order Taylor polynomial for `Sinc` for the expansion point `0`).